# In my facebook application's insights, it says that my Story impressions count is set to 0

Tags: facebook-insights, impressions

I actually have user that have posted content on their feed using my application and the actual number of stories is 310.

Why is my facebook application's insights not displaying the right number ? What could be preventing it ?

Thanks.